# Затирается результат первого из двух setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

Встроил ListView в основную разметку

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

ListView с такой разметкой (list_item.xml)

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="20dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_listW"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"

    android:text="@string/listW" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_listB"

    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"

    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
```

В основной активити я делаю так

```
       ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

   final String[] listW = new String[] {
            "A8", "C5", "F4", "H7", "W2",
            "F4", "H6", "K8", "N7", "B6",
            "B6", "M7", "R3"
    };
    final String[] listB = new String[] {
            "V2", "X5", "Z4", "N7", "B2",
            "D4", "C6", "V8", "N7", "V6",
            "A6", "H7", "M3"
    };
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    for(int h=0;h<listB.length;h++) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("listW", listW[h]);
        map.put("listB", listB[h]);
        arrayList1.add(map);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayList1,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"listW", "listB"},
            new int[]{R.id.text_view_listW, R.id.text_view_listB});



listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View itemClicked2, int position,
        long id) {
        String text2;
        LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) itemClicked2;
        TextView tv2;

        tv2 = (TextView) ll1.findViewById(R.id.text_view_listB);

        text2 = tv2.getText().toString();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " " + text2);


    }

});

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View itemClicked1, int position,
        long id) {
        LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) itemClicked1;
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) ll1.findViewById(R.id.text_view_listW);


        final String text1 = tv1.getText().toString();
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, " " + text1);
    }
});

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Т.е. в списке у меня есть два столбца. Как я полагаю я поставил по листенеру на каждый столбец, чтобы при нажатии на любой из них в лог выводилось содержимое ячейки. Но выводится только содержимое последнего листенера, а первый как бы затирается. Что не так?

p.s. В результате я хочу обрабатывать каждый клик по любому столбцу. Пока что получается или обрабатывается клик по первому столбцу или по второму(предыдущий затирается - почему, я уже понял).

Comment: listView может иметь только одного слушателя. Думаю вам лучше перенести логику обработки нажатий по TextView в адаптер

Comment: `Как я полагаю я поставил по листенеру на каждый столбец` -- неправильно полагаете. `setOnItemClickListener` устанавливает листнер (и удаляет предыдущий).

Comment: Перенести логику обработки в адаптер интересно, но я пока не представляю как это сделать. На поверхности лежит, то что Id этих столбцов разные (ll1.findViewById), а вот position одинаковые (т.к. в столбцах идут пары). Не могу понять к чему обратиться, чтобы в условии сравнить с Id (пробовал itemClicked2.getId() - но это не то). И по определённому Id назначать уже текст в лог.

Comment: Дополнил описание.

Comment: Пока что мне достаточно просто запустить Toast с отображением содержимого.

Comment: Всем спасибо. В-общем осилил с помощью этого урока http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/